# Get User's Login Credentials

Tags: c#, windows, sharepoint, credentials

I have an application which gets launched from our app-store. Its a standard win32 app.
We run it from the app-store because the application needs to have administration privileges to install some fonts and other items, which the app-store provides.

The application then connects to SharePoint and updates a list that tells us who and what font the users has installed. so here lies my problem.

The application uses the **DefaultNetworkCredentials** to connected to SharePoint, however in the  field called  **CreatedBy**  its filled out by the user that running the app. (in my case it’s the administration account supplied by the app store). What I would like is the user that’s log in to the computer not the user the application is running under. (if even possible).

Now I tried:

```
Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
SharePointWs.Credentials = Credentials;

Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
SharePointWs.Credentials = Credentials;
```

I don’t really see any different between the two of them other than the **DefaultNetworkCredentials** returns a little more info. and both returns the user running the application. The only other way around this would be to prompt for a username and password. this was something I was trying to avoid.

So my question would be is there any way to get the Credentials of the users that’s log in?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Off the top of my head I wonder if when an app runs as admin if the primary token is still the user, and it is impersonating admin.  You might be able to use this to investigate.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks good point I'll look into that... txs

Comment: If you just want to solve the issue of Created By in sharepoint, maybe this will help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/21f65f64-54d8-450f-b261-3d2f4ae42bd9/how-to-change-the-value-of-created-by-field-in-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: this is not a bad idea maybe I just need to create a new field and see if I can get the username using somthing like  String un = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;